# Proving that a set of functions with the Dirichlet convolution operation is a group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, dirichlet-convolution, kronecker-delta

I want to prove that the set $S:(f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R);f(1)\neq 0)$ with the [Dirichlet Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) operator is a group.

My process:

1. $f,g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R$ and $f*g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R$ so $f*g\in S$
2. $f*(g*h)=(f*g)*h$ via properties of Dirichlet Convolution
3. $f*\delta_{1}=\delta_{1}*f=f$ where the neutral element is the [Kronecker Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) of $1$.
4. $f*f^{-1}=\delta_{1}$ where $f^{-1}=\frac{-1}{f(1)}\sum_{d|n,d<n}f(\frac{n}{d})f^{-1}(d)$ follows from [Dirichlet Inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution#Dirichlet_inverse)

Thus all four criteria for a group are satisfied and $S:(S,*)$ is a group. Furthermore, since $f*g=g*f$, $S$ is abelian.

Is my process correct? I feel as though the inverse condition is a little iffy so if anyone can help verify if what I did was valid that would be great.

Comment: For the same question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147414/the-group-of-number-theoretic-functions) (including my answer). Complete proofs are in Apostol's book.

Comment: Will do, but is my process valid or not? And if it is not do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you have the same 4 items as the duplicate question, but the work is in the details. So far you only have claims without proof.

Comment: Also you'll want to look at sequences such that $a_1 = 1$ and $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges absolutely for $\Re(s)$ large enough. It forms a group under multiplication because  $\frac{1}{F(s)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-F(s))^k$ is a series of Dirichlet series and it converges absolutely for $\Re(s)$ large enough.